# Combining/Merging Boolean properties multiple Objects C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have got a ton of Objects, all of the same type. The only contain an int Id Property, the rest of the Properties are Boolean flags, also a ton of them.

**Question**: How can one combine them and create a new Object with `flag[x] = true`, where at least one of the objects has `flag[x] = true, else flag[x] = false`. (Sorry for this bad description, my English is not that good...)

**Example** (Pseudo-Code):

```
lst[0] = {0815, **true**, false, false, false}

lst[1] = {0815, false, false, **true**, false}

lst[2] = {0815, false, false, false, **true**}
```

shall result in

```
result = {0815, **true**, false, **true**, **true**}
```

I thought about grouping the Source using LINQ and then iterate through the groups, creating the new object manually.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to iterate through your collection and check whether a true exists :

```
bool hasFirstPropertyTrue = false;
bool hasSecondProprertyTrue = false;
[...]
foreach(item in yourCollection)
{
hasFirstProprertyTrue |= item.FirstProperty;
hasSecondPropertyTrue |= item.SecondProperty;
[...]
}
```

Then hasFirstPropertyTrue, hasSecondPropertyTrue ... will be true if there is at least one true in your properties

Comment: Thank you @Patatrack. I will try it this way.
Did not know there was an Compound assignment operator in C#. Extra Thanks for that! :-)